# In vertx-web backpressure example, why does removing observeOn increase latency?

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

In the [vertx-web backpressure example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/9738f2fc29729f1484049e2404c49c325a7987cc/rxjava-2-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/reactivex/web/backpressure/Server.java#L44-L53), what does `observeOn(RxHelper.scheduler(vertx.getDelegate()))` do, assuming I am starting Server verticle as a standard verticle.

I have 8 event loop threads and 8 instances of Server verticle deployed on an 8 core machine
I am not doing blocking IO call in route's handler

```
    server.requestStream()
      .toFlowable()
      .map(HttpServerRequest::pause)
      .onBackpressureDrop(req -> req.response().setStatusCode(503).end())
      .observeOn(RxHelper.scheduler(vertx.getDelegate())) // Why does removing this line increase CPU and latency?
      .subscribe(req -> {
        req.resume();
        router.accept(req);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because then you'll end up on the default scheduler which doesn't use the vertx event loop and is indeed slower due to the use of the normal threading model of java. Unless of course you configure rxjava's default schedulers to the event loop and the blocking thread pool with the helper methods from rxhelper.

```
RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(s -> RxHelper.scheduler(vertx));
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(s -> RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx));
RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(s -> RxHelper.scheduler(vertx));
```

Docs: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java2/#_scheduler_support

Comment: I have already configured the default RxJava schedulers.
Shouldn't `observeOn(RxHelper.scheduler` use the event-loop thread itself?